# JavaScript Return isn't returning

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple function checking if an array contains duplicates, I want it to return true if it does and false if it doesn't.

```
function containsDuplicates(a) {
    var hash = {};
    a.forEach((elem, index) => {
        if (hash[elem] === undefined) {
            hash[elem] = 1;
        } else {
            console.log('true')
            return true;
        }

        if (index === a.length - 1) {
            console.log('false')
            return false;
        }
    })
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
containsDuplicates(arr)
```

My console.log logs just fine but it doesn't seem to be hitting the return. My entire function returns undefined every time. Why is this the case?

Comment: Use `for ... of` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: You are using the wrong method. You should be using some() or every()

Answer (score 6):

You are returning from the callback that you passed to `forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from the callback you passed to foreach. You should try something like this instead.

```
 function hasDuplicates(array) {
  var keyStore = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (value in keyStore) {
      return true;
    }
    keyStore[value] = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```